# The best option

Tags: present-perfect

Which one is correct? If there are several possible answers, I would like to find some explanations, thank you.

1. I've been waiting for you for long time.
2. I've been waiting for you for so long (only emphasis?).
3. I've been waiting for you for long.

Comment: **For a long time** is the most idiomatic way to say it.  **For so long** can be used for emphasis, or comparison ("I've been waiting for you for so long that...")  **For long** is not correct *in this context*.  We would say "I won't wait for long" or "He wasn't here for long" but not "I've been waiting for long".  I'm not quite sure what the rule is, though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following up on what @stangdon said, using "For long" is only typically done with a negation. "I haven't been here for long", "She didn't stay for long". In this manner, it has the same meaning and level of emphasis as "for a long time" but one just shortens the phrase down to "for long". Again, only really works with a negation. If you are unsure, you can use "for a long time" for both negations and regular statements.